# SpringMVC: Passing value over URL Securely

Tags: spring-mvc

I saw that we can not pass values using **POST method** due to some security reason. So my question is

Is there any other better and secure process to do that? so that no one can see the passwords or values over the URL.

Comment: POST method does not send data over Url. But you can still see the data being passed in the browser console. If you want to protect your password or sensitive data like it, you can encrypt it and send via POST.

Answer (score 0):

Actually `POST method` is use to submit the **form** and the parameters will not pass through url. If you need to submit form then you should use same. Another if you want to pass values only you can use sessions,cookies,etc.

**GET** - Requests data from a specified resource

**POST** - Submits data to be processed to a specified resource

Comment: yeah now i just del method="POST" from here  
@RequestMapping()
    public String login(Model model, @ModelAttribute("LoginBean") LoginBean loginBean) {


 } .

 now code is working.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you include `spring-security`in your application? It will make your work easier.

Try checking out this link for reference:
http://www.baeldung.com/java-ee-spring-security